# How do I make use of the math symbols in a string (Python) it keeps concatenating

Tags: python, math, symbols

Good day,
I'm new to this and I need help!

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
bill = float(input("What was the total bill? $"))
tip = int(input("What tip should we give? 12, 15, 20? "))
people = input("How many people are spliting the bill? ")
total_bill = (f"{bill} * {tip / 100} / 5")
print(total_bill)
```

The only symbol that ran was the one in the braces.
I have tried various lines to get it done but no luck. the only time it worked was when i kept in the tip(0.12) directly. Can't even remember how anymore..
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code with bill = 120, tip = 15, people = 4 I get:

```
120.0 * 0.15 / 5
```

Apart from the fact that your don't use 'people' in the rest of your code why don't you just do something like:

```
total_bill = int(bill)*(1+int(tip)/100)
bill_per_person = total_bill/int(people)
print('The total bill is $', str(total_bill), 'and each person needs to pay $', str(bill_per_person))
```

Comment: Yes that ran fine, thanks. I added:     print("The total bill is $" , str(round(total_bill, 2)), "and each person needs to pay $", str(bill_per_person))   i.e. (round(toatal_bill, 2)) to be able to round it up to 2 decimals..